# Comments on questions, how do I add mine?

Tags: support, comments

1. How do I comment on someone's question? I don't see a button or link for this.
2. Is there a help page for this forum?
3. Can I ask questions about the forum on the forum?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: Not a forum, but a Questions & Answers site.

Answer (score 8):

1. You need 50 reputation points before you can leave comments. The easiest way to earn them is to post good questions and answers.  Also, you may get downvoted now and then early on;  try not to get disheartened!  Just keep improving your questions and answers, and the 50 reputation points should follow quickly.
2. Check out the [official FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [user generated FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
3. Questions about the forum belong on Meta

Also, you can always leave comments on your own questions, answers, and any answers to questions you have asked. Even with 1 reputation.

Good luck and welcome to Meta Stackoverflow!