# Why am I unable to post comments on certain threads

Tags: support, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments on questions, how do I add mine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/comments-on-questions-how-do-i-add-mine)

Was just looking at a question on SO where other people had posted comments yet I was unable to post a comment.  What is going on here? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the question had been turned into a wiki?

Answer (score 0):

You need 50 rep to post comments, except on your own questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Comments on questions, how do I add mine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/comments-on-questions-how-do-i-add-mine)